# Only execute script if branch is master in TravisCI

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, travis-ci

I'm new to TravisCI and this may be a very silly question, but I'm trying to write the travis config in a way that it only deploys to Firebase when the current branch is master.
That is, only when code is pushed to master or when a PR is merged with master, the firebase deploy command executes. The deploy command should be **not** be executed when other branches are pushed to, or when PRs are made.
Here's what I have so far:

```
language: node_js
node_js: 12.16.1
script: echo "Running travis-ci"
install: 
  - npm install -g firebase-tools
  - npm i react-scripts
script:
  - yarn add react
  - yarn test
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then yarn build; fi
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then firebase deploy --project testproj8876 --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN; fi
branches:
  only:
    - master
```

Since I'm not too familiar with the conventions yet, any improvements/suggestions would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Firebase is supported directly by Travis. See [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/firebase/).

Thereby, I recommend using the solution described in the link above.

```yaml
deploy:
  provider: firebase
  token:
   secure: "YOUR ENCRYPTED token"
```

As for your condition, you can check one of my .travis.yml file [here](https://github.com/73VW/Publishing-to-PyPI-with-pbr-and-Travis/blob/master/.travis.yml) and the documentation [there (Conditional Deployments)](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment-v2/conditional)

The following part is what you need:

```yaml
deploy:
  cleanup: false
  on:
    branch:
    - master
```

If you still have questions, feel free to ask.